# How to intercept http response in feign and spring boot before ErrorDecoder invoked

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I need to intercept HTTP response and alter HTTP status code.
for example, I might change 200 to 400 (based on the response object itself) so that the ErrorDecoder should be invoked.

I need to do this without extending the `feign.Client` class! (in fact, the `feign.httpclient.ApacheHttpClient`  which I am using is final!)

I tried to provide an implementation for `ResponseMapper` but it seems the response mapper (and the `Decoder` that I used to override) isn't invoked until the HTTP status check is done inside `AsyncResponseHandler#handleResponse`!

I am talking mainly here about how the implementation of [SynchronousMethodHandler](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/SynchronousMethodHandler.java) and [AsyncResponseHandler](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/AsyncResponseHandler.java) works.

***To sum it up***, my main issue is that `AsyncResponseHandler#handleResponse` doesn't invoke the `Decoder` (hence the `ResponseMapper`) before the `ErrorDecoder`, and if it does then the `ResponseMapper` can do the HTTP status code I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override this shortcoming, I'd to refere to the implementation class in the code (instead of depending on the auto configuration of spring boot)

```java
@Bean
public Client feignClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
    var client = new ApacheHttpClient(httpClient);
    return (request, options) -> convertResponse(client.execute(request, options));
}

private Response convertResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SynchronousMethodHandler** uses **feign.Logger** to print logs before and after the feign request process unless the log level is NONE. The calling sequence is as follows:

1. `logger.logResuest(configKey, logLevel, request)`
2. `response = client.execute(request, options)`
3. `response = logger.logAndRebufferResponse(configKey, logLevel, response, elapsedTime)`

This logger is created by **DefaultFeignLoggerFactory#create()**. If you define your own logger and register it as a SringBean,  **DefaultFeignLoggerFactory** should use your own logger to print logs, you can see it in `FeignClientsConfigurations` that the logger is `@Autowired(required = false)`.
So you should define your own logger, for example:

```java
public class MyFeignLogger extends Slf4jLogger {

    @Override
    protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(String configKey, Logger.Level logLevel, Response response, long elapsedTime) {
        Response rsp = super.logAndRebufferResponse(configKey, logLevel, response, elapsedTime);
        //you can change response status here by java reflect. 
        if(xxxx) {
            ReflectUtil.setFieldValue(rsp, "status", 400);
        }
        return rsp;
    }
}
```

Then register this class as Bean:

```java
@Configuration
@AutoConfiguration(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
public class MyFeignConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Logger feignLogger() {
        return new MyFeignLogger();
    }
}
```

It works.